# BigQuery cacheHit property

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using the BigQuery API to run a query with the following code:

```
query = (
    'SELEC ...'
)

# API request - starts the query
query_job = client.query(
    query,
    location='US'
)

results = query_job.result()
```

The query works and outputs expected results.
However, I am not able to verify use of the cache.

[Docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results#verifying_use_of_the_cache):

> If you are using the BigQuery API, the `cacheHit` property in the query
>   result is set to true.

I am trying to access **results.cacheHit**, but it does work out.

`AttributeError: 'RowIterator' object has no attribute 'cacheHit'`

What am I doing wrong? How can I see the use of cache with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote you are using from docs refers to the REST API (cacheHit is in the response of the [getQueryResults](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults) method).

What you need instead is [query_job.cache_hit](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.cache_hit.html)