# How do I access the cacheHit property of my BigQuery result set?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Apparently, when using the BigQuery API, there is a `cacheHit` property of a BigQuery result. I've tried finding this property and I'm not sure how I need to access it. Here's my Java code that uses the BigQuery API. `cacheHit` isn't a property of the TableResult `tr` that I get:

```
try
{
    QueryJobConfiguration queryJobConfiguration =

        QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(
                "mySQLqueryText"
        )
        .setUseLegacySql(false)
        .setAllowLargeResults(false)
        .setUseQueryCache(true)
        .build();

    try {
        TableResult tr = bigQuery.query(queryJobConfiguration);

        Iterable<FieldValueList> rowList = tr.getValues();

        ....
    }
    catch (BigQueryException e) {
        // do stuff
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I looked at this question - [BigQuery cacheHit property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51668227/bigquery-cachehit-property)

... but that's not Java, and I haven't found any `results()` property I can use, as suggested in that question.

There's some documentation here about the [JobStatistics2](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#jobstatistics2) object, that apparently has a `cacheHit` property.

I can get a `JobStatistics` (*not* a `JobStatistics2` object), like this:

```
QueryJobConfiguration queryJobConfiguration =

    QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(
            "myQueryString"
    )
    .setUseLegacySql(false)
    .setAllowLargeResults(false)
    .setUseQueryCache(true)
    .build();

    JobId jobId = JobId.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    Job queryJob = bigQuery.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(queryJobConfiguration).setJobId(jobId).build());

try {

    queryJob = queryJob.waitFor();

    if (queryJob != null) {

        JobStatistics js = queryJob.getStatistics();

    Iterable<FieldValueList> rowList = bigQuery.query(queryJobConfiguration).getValues();
```

... but I don't see any `cacheHit` property on `js`. When I try creating a `JobStatistics2` instead, by changing the line where I'm instantiating `JobStatistics`, like this:

```
JobStatistics2 js = queryJob.getStatistics();
```

I get an error `Type parameter S has incompatible upper bounds: JobStatistics and JobStatistics2`. This doesn't mean much, and when I Google the error there are no useful results.

I'm not finding the Google documentation too useful. How can I access the `cacheHit` property, and still obtain my `rowList` as shown in the code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QueryStatistics` is one of the nested classes of `JobStatistics` as can be seen [here](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/com/google/cloud/bigquery/JobStatistics.html) and has a [`getCacheHit()`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/com/google/cloud/bigquery/JobStatistics.QueryStatistics.html#getCacheHit--) method:

```java
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.JobStatistics.QueryStatistics;

...

QueryStatistics js = queryJob.getStatistics();

System.out.println(js.getCacheHit());
```

See full code [here](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/92e696d53f5f3aa9b4a2ccdaaed2a8a3) for my test.

Regarding `JobStatistics2` this is for `com.google.api.services.bigquery` library and not `com.google.cloud.bigquery`. In that case you could use [`getQuery()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/JobStatistics.html#getQuery--) from `JobStatistics` to get a `JobStatistics2` object and then use [`getCacheHit()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/JobStatistics2.html#getCacheHit-java.lang.Boolean-).

Comment: Fantastic answer - one of the best efforts I've seen on StackOverflow. Thanks very much :)